# Installing VMware tools on Metasploitable2

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, metasploit

I'm learning Linux. I have installed Metasploitable2  on VMware workstation. I am unable to install VMware tools on my VM, so I can do copying/pasting etc. How can this be done? I know I first need to mount the virtual drive but after that I'm stuck. Also, should I be using `su` for this?

Comment: Are you using kali linux 2 ?

Comment: @GAD3R I am using Kali Linux (kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso) but how is that relevant since Metasploitable2 is it's own virtual machine?

Comment: Yes of course Metasploitable2 is a VM and metasploit is a program, please edit.

Comment: List the contents of the mount point directory and note if the filename of the VMware Tools tar installer exist or not.

Comment: @GAD3R how do you do that?

Comment: I tried following these directions and after `mount` couldn't see anything that looked like CD https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc_50%2FGUID-08BB9465-D40A-4E16-9E15-8C016CC8166F.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the VmWare Tools from Vmware.

If using Debian, Ubuntu or Kali, you can install the open-vm-tools with:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

From https://packages.debian.org/jessie/open-vm-tools

> The Open Virtual Machine Tools (open-vm-tools) project is an open
>   source implementation of VMware Tools. It is a suite of virtualization
>   utilities and drivers to improve the functionality, user experience
>   and administration of VMware virtual machines.

Usually, the open VM Tools are simpler to install and manage, and are also automatically upgraded when upgrading the operating system.

As Metaspoitable2 is based of Ubuntu, the best be would be to find a compatible deb of open-vm-tools and try to install it; however I am not familiar with that distribution.

Comment: It says `coudln't find package open-vm-tools`

Comment: I'm running Metasploitable2

Comment: I added to the answer.